# What's the difference between "такой" and "такой же"?

Tags: словоупотребление, значения

I understand what the word means, but I just can't pin down any difference between the two choices. They seem absolutely identical, but Russian speakers seem to prefer the second version:

```
Это такая машина какая есть у Пети.

Это такая же машина какая есть у Пети.
```

Answer (score 4):

The meanings are quite distinct:

- такая = such (a)
- такая же = the same

Examples:

- Такая машина есть только у Пети! - Only Pete has such a car!
- У Васи такая же машина, как у Пети. - Vasya has the same car as Pete.

Comment: +1, but would you like to expand this answer, adding more details and examples? Like, phrases where the difference would be obvious.

Comment: @IgorG Sure - done!

Comment: Both Russian sentences have exactly the same meaning. Your explanation does not make sense given those two sentences

Comment: I tend to feel that V.V.'s answer is more accurate

Comment: @afora377 I would argue that the first sentence can have a different meaning. "Такая же" stresses that these cars are the same, but if "такая" in the first sentence is used as "such (a)", then the first sentence stresses what kind of car this is, not that it's the same.

Answer (score 3):

Your phrase shows comparison.

Это такая машина, как у Пети.
Это такая же машина, как у Пети.

The meaning is the same. To show resemblance.
Же is used as an intensifier of такая.
We prefer the second variant.
Же in this context is a particle. They don't carry any meaning, but do carry emotions. Же is used after pronouns and pronominal adverbs to underline
similarity , resemblance, permanence.
Такая же погода. Такой же климат.

Comment: I disagree about the preference. The meaning is slightly different and depends on the context.

Comment: The second phrase is emotional, but the meaning is the same. Particles don't have meanings. And people prefer emotions.

Comment: And you have one and the same context.

Answer (score 1):

I think the previous answer needs clarification.

While "*такая*" means **such**, it also means "**of the same kind**" or "**of this (particular) kind**" - depending on the context, but it doesn't mean *exactly the same*. I think that's what it could mean in the first sentence.

It can also mean "**either**" as in "*такая или такая/другая*".

To complete the picture, it can also emphasize the other word: "*такая красивая машина*" means "**such a beautiful car**" or "**a very beautiful car**".

So, it's not a matter of the Russian speaker's preference, but it's very context-dependent.

Edit - translation for the second sentence: "*Это такая же машина какая есть у Пети.*" means "**This is [exactly] the same car that Petya has.**"

Comment: So, you feel that the two sentences may be either identical, or have the following translations: (1) "This is a type of car that Petya owns, (2) "This is the same car that Petya owns". But then in (2) because Petya cannot own exactly the same car, semantically it's just the same type of car. And we are back to V.V.'s answer regarding the emphasis with "же". Does this sound right?

Comment: This is why it's hard to answer questions here sometimes. I think it may depend on a context. For example, when one is pointing to the car. Or it can have the same meaning. This small additional word makes me think that the car is exactly the same (make, model, probably even color). It serves as an emphasys. But maybe I'm little over-analysing.